# How can I test Android Market Filtering before publishing my app?

Tags: android, google-play

I want to modify my AndroidManifest.xml with various permissions and features and test how my app will be filtered according to those changes.  Is there any way to do this without publishing my app, which will notify users of an update?

Answer (score 3):

How about trying it with a test app, that you publish and test filtering, then just remove from the marketplace?

Or you can upload an older version, with the test filters, then the newer version will automatically overwrite it, and since it will have correct filtering you should be okay.

Answer (score 0):

It's a cool idea, but impossible.

I would suggest uploading to the market and postpone the marketing effort until you are sure it's ok.

Comment: Doesn't this beg the question? How can you be sure it's ok without testing? How can you test without publishing?

Comment: The reality is that you can't test that without publishing.